# Google Earth Engine - Selected layers not updating

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to seek assistance on the code below. My maps is not updating after I choose the layer in the dropdown list.

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 12;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var S2021 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',15))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                  
var S2020 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',15))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);                  
                  
var S2021_style = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var S2020_style = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(103.804, 1.3714, 12);

Map.addLayer(S2021.mean(), S2021_style, '2021');
Map.addLayer(S2020.mean(), S2020_style, '2020');

var leftMap = ui.Map()
var rightMap = ui.Map()

var S2021_img = ui.Map.Layer(S2021.mean(),S2021_style)
var S2020_img = ui.Map.Layer(S2020.mean(),S2020_style)

var S2021_layer = leftMap.layers()
var S2020_layer = rightMap.layers()

S2021_layer.add(S2021_img)
S2020_layer.add(S2020_img)

var S2021_label = ui.Label('Sentinel 2021')
S2021_label.style().set('position', 'bottom-left')

var S2020_label = ui.Label('Sentinel 2020')
S2020_label.style().set('position', 'bottom-right')

leftMap.add(S2021_label)
rightMap.add(S2020_label)
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel ({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  wipe: true
})

ui.root.clear()

ui.root.add(splitPanel)

var linkPanel = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap])

//Set the flow
var horizontalFlow = ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
var verticalFlow = ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical')

//Spectrum Lists
var imageList = ["S2021_layer","S2020_layer"]

var imageSelect_1 = ui.Select(imageList,"Select Image")
var imageSelect_2 = ui.Select(imageList,"Select Image")

//query labels
var image1Label = ui.Label("Layer: ")
var query1Panel = ui.Panel([imageSelect_1])
var image1Panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets:[image1Label,query1Panel],
  layout:verticalFlow,
  style: {position: 'top-left'}
  })
leftMap.add(image1Panel)

var image2Label = ui.Label("Layer: ")
var query2Panel = ui.Panel([imageSelect_2])
var image2Panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets:[image2Label,query2Panel],
  //layout:verticalFlow,
  style: {position: 'top-right'}
  })
rightMap.add(image2Panel)

// This function changes the given map to show the selected image.
  function updateMap(selection) {
    mapToChange.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(image[selection]));
  }

var linker = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! If you want people to have look to your question, you should on your side try to reduce the provided amont of code to review (I'm sure you can narrow down to a simple reproductible example) + if you really can't reduce it, provide code that we can test ourself: here the `geometry` variable is missing preventing me from helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the dropdown lists work; you can use the next solution:

- Create image dictionary
- Create function to get image from image collection (where the collection includes your two images)
- Create left and right map displaying a default image.
- Create function to change map.

This is my code:

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 12;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var S2021 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',15))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                  
var S2020 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',15))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);                  
                  
/*var S2021_style = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var S2020_style = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(103.804, 1.3714, 12); */

// create image dictionary
var images = {
  '2020': getImage(0),
  '2021': getImage(1),
};

// --------------Function to get image from image collection --------------------
function getImage(number) {
  number = ee.Number(number)
  var collection = ee.ImageCollection([S2020.mean(), S2021.mean()]) // collection of images
  var listOfImages = collection.toList(collection.size()); // list of images
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(number)); // get individual image
  return image.visualize({bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}); //style
}

/*
Map.addLayer(S2021.mean(), S2021_style, '2021');
Map.addLayer(S2020.mean(), S2020_style, '2020');

var leftMap = ui.Map()
var rightMap = ui.Map()

var S2021_img = ui.Map.Layer(S2021.mean(),S2021_style)
var S2020_img = ui.Map.Layer(S2020.mean(),S2020_style)

var S2021_layer = leftMap.layers()
var S2020_layer = rightMap.layers()

S2021_layer.add(S2021_img)
S2020_layer.add(S2020_img)

var S2021_label = ui.Label('Sentinel 2021')
S2021_label.style().set('position', 'bottom-left')

var S2020_label = ui.Label('Sentinel 2020')
S2020_label.style().set('position', 'bottom-right')

leftMap.add(S2021_label)
rightMap.add(S2020_label)
*/
//---------------- Create the left map, and have it display layer 0.
var leftMap = ui.Map();
leftMap.setControlVisibility(false);
var leftSelector = addLayerSelector(leftMap, 0, 'top-left');

//----------------- Create the right map, and have it display layer 1.
var rightMap = ui.Map();
rightMap.setControlVisibility(false);
var rightSelector = addLayerSelector(rightMap, 1, 'top-right');

//----- Adds a layer selection widget to the given map, to allow users to change
//----- which image is displayed in the associated map.
function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Select image');

  // This function changes the given map to show the selected image.
  function updateMap(selection) {
    mapToChange.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(images[selection]));
  }

  // Configure a selection dropdown to allow the user to choose between images,
  // and set the map to update when a user makes a selection.
  var select = ui.Select({items: Object.keys(images), onChange: updateMap});
  select.setValue(Object.keys(images)[defaultValue], true);

  var controlPanel =
      ui.Panel({widgets: [label, select], style: {position: position}});

  mapToChange.add(controlPanel);
}

var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel ({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  wipe: true
})

ui.root.clear()

ui.root.add(splitPanel)

var linkPanel = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap])

// ----------set center using left map
leftMap.setCenter(103.804, 1.3714, 12);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, HMSP!

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer was correct, please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.