# Dropdown does not update map on Google Earth Engine (Geemap Python package)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, widget, geemap, dropdownlist

I have estimated NDVI and NDWI for a specific area based on Sentinel 2 images via gee library on Python (Google Earth Engine). More specifically, I have created two functions (one for each index) and applied them to one `ee.FeatureCollection`.

I have created a dropdown menu with two options: ndvi and ndwi.

I want to toggle and update the map based on a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is shown on the map. The problem is that the map does not update when I click the other option.
[image]

The following code is written on a Jupyter Notebook. I have checked the following post but it is not still clear.
[Google Earth Engine layers do not update on widget selection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437535/google-earth-engine-layers-do-not-update-on-widget-selection)

```
import ee
import geemap
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Create a Dropdown widget
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['NDVI', 'NDWI'],
    value='NDWI',
    description='Index:'
)
    
Map = geemap.Map()

countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
thessalia = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME','Thessalia'))

# Functions
def calculate_ndvi(image):
    ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(["B8", "B4"])
    return ndvi

def calculate_ndwi(image):
    ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(["B8", "B3"])
    return ndvi

## Before the event
sentinel2_before = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')\
.filterDate('2023-08-31', '2023-09-01').filterBounds(thessalia)


# Applyinh the indices
ndvi_collection_before = sentinel2_before.map(calculate_ndvi)
ndwi_collection_before = sentinel2_before.map(calculate_ndwi)

ndvi_vis = {"min": -1, "max": 1, "palette": ["red", "yellow", "green"]}
ndwi_vis = {"min": -1, "max": 1, "palette": ["orange", "white", "blue"]}
Map.addLayer(ndwi_collection_before, ndwi_vis, 'NDVI')

def update_map(index):
    Map.remove_layer(ndvi_collection_before)
    Map.remove_layer(ndwi_collection_before)
    if index == 'NDVI':
        Map.addLayer(ndvi_collection_before, ndvi_vis, 'NDVI')  # Add NDVI layer
        Map
    elif index == 'NDWI':
        Map.addLayer(ndwi_collection_before, ndwi_vis, 'NDWI')  # Add NDWI layer
        Map
        
# Calculate NDVI for each image in the collection
output_control = ipyleaflet.WidgetControl(widget=dropdown, position='bottomright')

dropdown.observe(update_map, names='value')

# Add the Dropdown widget to the map
Map.add_control(output_control)

Map.setCenter(22, 38, 7)
Map
```